# WPF and FontAwesome problem with hyphenated icons

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-interface, font-awesome

I am using FontAwesome in my WPF app for icons.

Everything works as expected with single name icons, but whenever I try to use a hyphenated icon name, the font does not understand this, and either does not draw anything, or it draws the two icons (left and right of the hyphen) individually (if they exist).

**This draws the user icon. Great.**

```
<!--FontAwesome Font applied in style-->
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource mainButtonImage}" Margin="5" Text="user"></TextBlock>
```

[image]

**This, draws the User icon, a "-" and a circle icon. It should be the "user-circle" icon.**

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource mainButtonImage}" Margin="5" Text="user-circle"></TextBlock>
```

[image]

It should be drawing this: https://fontawesome.com/icons/user-circle?style=regular

When I test in notepad on my system, it works as expected.
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to escape the hyphen or use the Unicode value directly with \u ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This does not work: "user&#45;circle" (Although it does still draw the hyphen on the screen, like it normally does.

Comment: This also does not work.. Although I am not entirely confident I am escaping it correctly..
Text="{} user-circle"

Comment: Ask them directly at their website then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented the "user-circle" icon in two ways below:

**Method 1:**

1.You can install `FontAwesome.WPF` in project's `Package NuGet Manager`.

2.Import `xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"` into your XAML code.

3.Use it into your TextBlock like this:

```
<fa:FontAwesome Icon="UserCircle" FontSize="100"></fa:FontAwesome>
```

**Method 2:**

1.Download font awesome at [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

2.Unzip the file and copy font to the project as a resource. The path is `\Font\fa-regular-400.ttf`.

3.Add `FontAwesome` style in Window.Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FontAwesome">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Font/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" /> 
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

4.Use style in TextBlock and write the Unicode code of user-circle in Text like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#xf2bd;" Style="{DynamicResource FontAwesome}" />
```

Maybe you can refer to these two methods to implement your program.

Comment: I am already using your 2nd suggestion, but that is where I had my issue. Your solution to use "&#xf2bd;" does work, but can you elaborate on where you came about using this? I see that f3bd is classified as the unicode for this icon, but where/why do you get the "&#x" pre-fix from?

Comment: this solution does not work for the duotone font of fontawesome... like the icon "beer-mug#", you have to add a # to color every element