# How to use parameters or binding for WPF buttons to change fa icons in XAML styles

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, font-awesome

I made a XAML style for a button in WPF to be used for menu items. When creating the menu list i want to change the icon (FontAwesome icon) based on a parameter i put into my  code to keep it clean and use the same style for the other elements in my button.

However so far I've found that it's not possible to send parameters to styles. So I was wondering how i can achieve it. I also tried Icon="{Binding Path=Icon}" but i believe this doesn't apply for each button seperately.

What i have:
[All icons are the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYI0w.png)

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MenuHome" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">Home</Button>
```

What i want:
[All icons are different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqOsB.png)

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MenuHome" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}" Icon="Home" IconColor="Green">Home</Button>
```

Code:

```
    <!-- Menu item button style unclicked -->
    <Style x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF33334C"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Grid Name="GridMouseOver" Background="Black" Opacity="0.2" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="AddressBook" Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="Gainsboro" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="60,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridMouseOver" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    
    <!-- Sub menu item button style -->
    <Style x:Key="SubMenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF33334C"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Grid Name="GridMouseOver" Background="Black" Opacity="0.2" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="{Binding Path=Icon}" Height="20" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="Gainsboro" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="60,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridMouseOver" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<!-- Button creation code -->
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <!-- Menu grid -->
        <Grid x:Name="Menu" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF33334C">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition  Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" LastChildFill="False">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MenuHome" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">Home</Button>
                <!-- Add visibility Visibility="Collapsed" to the sub menu dock panel-->
                <DockPanel x:Name="SubMenuHome" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="SubMenuHome1" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuItem}">Sub Home 1</Button>
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="SubMenuHome2" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuItem}">Sub Home 2</Button>
                </DockPanel>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MenuProject" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">Project</Button>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MenuTools" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}">Tools</Button>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="TitleBar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="#FF33334C">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="ChildForm" Background="#FF333346">

        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Excuse me but the code posted is a little messed up, it need some re-organizing. Anyway, the default `Button` control doesn't have `Icon` and `IconColor` properties so you have to either use attached properties or extend the standard `Button` to add those properties. Also the template used for button can be simplified since `Border` can be direct container and include a horizontal `StackPanel` which host both `fa:ImageAwesome` and `TextBlock` (or `ContentPresenter`). Once you have `Icon` and `IconColor` implemented, then they can be bound to `fa:ImageAwesome` (`Icon` and `Foreground`).

Comment: I am new to WPF and XAML so I learn as i go. Had a good laugh on your comment actually as I was happy that it was working and a bit proud. But apparently, to a more experienced programmer it's awful. I will certainly try to implement attached properties in the near future as i now know on what term to continue my search. I already changed the border content to a stackpanel. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Don't get me wrong but clean code is always easier to debug and better for performance. Your code is already a good start and going in the right direction :) If you implement something for missing properties (in case the accepted answer didn't fit your needs) and still need help with icons, just update your question with your changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to refer to the following code to bind the Icon to the Tag content of the Button. It contains two methods, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66418667/15181473).

```
<Style x:Key="FontAwesome">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Font/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF33334C"/>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Font/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Grid Name="GridMouseOver" Background="Black" Opacity="0.2" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType=Button} }" Height="30" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="Gainsboro" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="60,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridMouseOver" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItem2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF33334C"/>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Font/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Grid Name="GridMouseOver" Background="Black" Opacity="0.2" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType=Button} }" FontSize="22" Margin="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource  FontAwesome}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="Gainsboro" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="60,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridMouseOver" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<Grid x:Name="Menu" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF33334C">
               ...
               <DockPanel Grid.Row="2" LastChildFill="False">
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MenuHome" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem}" Tag="home">Home</Button>
                <DockPanel x:Name="SubMenuHome" DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="SubMenuHome1" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuItem}">Sub Home 1</Button>
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="SubMenuHome2" Style="{StaticResource SubMenuItem}">Sub Home 2</Button>
                </DockPanel>
                <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="MenuProject" Style="{StaticResource MenuItem2}"  Tag="&#xf542;">Project
                </Button>
            </DockPanel>
            </Grid>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It indeed did what I wanted to achieve. I had to replace the fontfamily to "pack://application:,,,/FontAwesome.WPF;component/#FontAwesome" as i was using Fontawesome.wpf. However i noticed that not all icons are usable in this so i will try to use your full package next. Do you know if the proposed solution to use Tag is a commonly used one? I feel like if I might want to use Tag in the future this won't be possible anymore. Could Binding Tag be changed to a custom parameter as Khiro sort of suggested? Thanks a lot for the clear answer though. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I improved my code with the help from the answer/info above.

I Implemented FontAwesome 5 instead of the Nuget package FontAwesome.WPF as it holds more icons.

1. Download the resource files from the website

   [Download Link FA5 Desktop](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-desktop/setup/getting-started)
2. Create a folder named Fonts in your project (ProjectName.csproj)

   Folder has to be in this level because making multiple folder structures first (Fonts/otf/FA5.otf) didn't work for me.
3. Rename it to something easier to type if you like

   FaFreeSolid for me
4. Copy it into the Fonts folder
5. Add it to the project

   Project menu -> show all files -> Solution explorer -> Right click the .otf file -> add to project
6. Open the .otf font file in Windows and check the name at the top. Copy it for now
7. Create a Resource dictionary

   RMB ProjectName.csproj -> Add -> ResourceDictionary (WPF) -> Named it FontAwesomeResources
8. Open the file and create a FontFamily

   Part 1: Key=name to call it with

   Part 2: Path to the font file

   Part 3: #FontName from point 6

Code:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="FaFreeSolid">/Fonts/FaFreeSolid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free</FontFamily>
```

9. Go to App.xaml to call the resource for the whole project

Code:

```
    <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="FontAwesomeResources.xaml"/>  
    </Application.Resources>
```

10. I used the resource in a textblock for the Text property. This property then sets the icon image. The text should be the same as on the website. I noticed that names with a - in its name don't work so you have to use the &#x prefix in the text and use the icon code number behind it. (example: &#xf2b9 = AdressBook)

    [FA Cheat Sheet](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet)

This part makes the "Home" icon show up:

```
<TextBlock Text="Home" Foreground="DarkRed" FontFamily="{StaticResource FaFreeSolid}" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<!-- Menu item button style unclicked -->
    <Style x:Key="btnMenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Grid Name="GridMouseOver" Background="Black" Opacity="0.2" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Home" Foreground="DarkRed" FontFamily="{StaticResource FaFreeSolid}" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="Gainsboro" FontSize="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="GridMouseOver" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The next problem I have to tackle is creating a dependancy property to set the icon image and icon color through a property when creating a button based on this style.